# Disproving that a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let assume that the sequence $\{d(x_n,0)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ (In the euclidean space) is strictly increasing.
>
> Prove/Disprove: $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges

I am trying to grasp it conceptually but did not manage.

The sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are bounded, therefore each element of the sequence is bounded and we can look at it, as a sequence of points in a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now we take the distance of the a point from the origin, and the distance is strictly increasing, but how can it be if the points themselves are bounded?

Comment: Cauchy Criterion?

Comment: Hint: note that $d(x_n,0)$ is unaware of sign changes to any of the components of $x_n$.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, but if $|x_{i}|<M$ so will $d(x_n,0)$ be

Comment: @gbox $d(x_n,0)$ will converge to some limit, but does that mean that $x_n$ will converge? Note that $d(x_n,0)$ is constant on any sphere centered at the origin.

Comment: @Bungo ahh got it, I was thinking about $d(x_{n},0)$ all the time, of course $x_{n}$ does not have to converges :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following sequence in $\mathbb{R^d}$: for $n\geq 1$,
$$x_n=\left((-1)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right),0,\dots,0\right).$$
Does it satisfy the hypothesis?

Comment: So $d(0,x_{n})=|1-\frac{1}{n}|$?

Comment: Yes and $|1-\frac{1}{n}|=1-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: and it is strictly increasing, even if it is bounded by $1$?

Comment: Yes. Are you able to verify it?

Comment: Yep, feeling a bit silly as I tried to prove $d(x_{n},0)$ converges/diverges and not the sequence

Comment: @gbox Well done!